# Is it possible to pair Microsoft wireless keyboard/mouse with Bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

I have purchased [Wireless Desktop 2000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-desktop-2000) from Microsoft, a 2.4G wireless mouse and keyboard with a USB transceiver.

After a while I lost the USB transceiver, so I'm trying to connect them with laptop's built-in Bluetooth, 
(*I know it won't work with non-Microsoft transceiver*), and when I try to pair them with Bluetooth I can't find the product in search's results but **I'm wondering** maybe somebody has a tricky way or got a solution to pair hidden devices!

Comment: What makes you think they're even using Bluetooth?

Comment: @DanielB I'm not sure, but I know that there are other products of Microsoft works with built-in bluetooth

Answer (score 2):

'Wireless' and 'Bluetooth' are two different technologies for doing the same thing. It'd be like trying to fill an electric car with petrol - sure, both petrol and electric cars exist, and both can drive on the same roads, but the underlying technology for them to perform this function is radically different.

Unless your Keyboard/Mouse explicitly say something like 'Bluetooth compatible' then they won't connect via a Bluetooth connection.